# match regex patten between two pattern

Tags: c#, regex

Hi I am newbie in RegEx operations. I have a text like

```
[JUNCTIONS]
;ID                 Elev            Demand          Pattern         
 3                  50              100                                 ;
 4                  50              30                                  ;
 5                  50              20                                  ;
 6                  40              20                                  ;
 7                  50              5                                   ;
 8                  30              5                                   ;
 9                  30              5                                   ;
 2                  50              80                                  ;
 10                 50              70                                  ;
 11                 50              30                                  ;
 12                 50              52                                  ;
 13                 50              40                                  ;
 14                 50              40                                  ;
 15                 50              10                                  ;
 16                 50              10                                  ;
 17                 50              10                                  ;
 18                 0               0                                   ;
 19                 0               0                                   ;

[RESERVOIRS]
;ID                 Head            Pattern         
 1                  100                                 ;

[TANKS]
```

I want to create a pattern and output the text between `[JUNCTIONS]` and `[RESERVOIRS]` then `[RESERVOIRS]` to `[TANKS]` then so on. [XXXX] is not known to me. I want to get text inside [XXX] to [XXX]. How can i do that?

Comment: What format is this? A plain text file? Also: Are you sure you absolutely need to use a RegEx for this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the regex:

```
(?=(\[\S+\].*?\[\S+\]))
```

or

```
(?=(\[(?:JUNCTIONS|RESERVOIRS)\].*?\[(?:RESERVOIRS|TANKS)\]))
```

Assuming you want to handle all the `[...]` things from your input.

Note: Use the make sure you are handling multiple line regex matching from your c#. And don't for get to escape the `\` character if you need.

Comment: Thank you but I am not able to manage  [...] can you please modify your post then it will very helpful.

Comment: I have updated the regex. If you need more words there, just add with `|` as i have used.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some c# code to do the match, and get the results.

Be sure to add error checking, for example to make sure that the match actually worked.

Note the Singleline flag - this lets the dot (.) match all characters, including newlines. You'll also probably need to cleanup and trim the output, to remove any trailing newlines, etc.

```
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(test, @"^\[JUNCTIONS\](.*)\[RESERVOIRS\](.*)\[TANKS\](.*)$", RegexOptions.Singleline);
GroupCollection groups = matches[0].Groups;

// JUNCTIONS text
Console.WriteLine(groups[1]);

// RESERVOIRS text
Console.WriteLine(groups[2]);
```

**Edit** - Updated to match OP's changes

If you want to match an unspecified number of matches, its a little trickier. This regex will match a [TEXT] block and anything that comes after it, until it its a [ character. The way to use this regex is to loop over the MatchCollection for each region, and use .groups[1] for the text and .groups[2] for the body.

```
MatchCollection matches = 
    Regex.Matches(test, @"\[([\w+]+)\]([^\[]+)?", RegexOptions.Singleline);

// for each block / section of the document
foreach(Match match in matches){

     GroupCollection groups = match.Groups;
     // [TEXT] part will be here
     Console.WriteLine(groups[1]);

     // The rest will be here
     Console.WriteLine(groups[2]);

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why use a regex?

Assuming you can read this input text one line at a time, it will probably be quicker and easier to just loop over the lines, and output those you need. Some variant of:

**Update:**

In response to you comment below; you can probably use this to skip any lines with `[something]` in them, and print out the rest:

```
// Pattern: Any instance of [] with one or more characters of between them:
var pattern = @"\[.+\]"; 
while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    if(!Regex.IsMatch(line, pattern)) // Skip lines that match
    {
        Console.WriteLine(line);
    }      
}
```

Comment: @ShantanuBanerjee Ok, updated my answer. Hope this is more helpful. :)